# Suggested Edits flag shouldn't appear when all edit reviews are complete

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits

Whenever there are suggested edits pending approval, I get a flag in the top navbar with the number of edits pending allowing me to go directly to the Suggested Edits review queue:

[image]

This is fine most of the time, however when I have completed the maximum reviews for the day, the badge remains there:

[image]

When all review tasks have been completed for the day, the flag should disappear from the top bar.

Comment: @honk this is a dupe of that, true, but neither the dupe nor the SE Meta question linked from it has an authoritative answer and are a couple of years old.